# UIActivity -- Share via Message causes "To:" text input to be clipped

Tags: ios

Using UIActivity and sharing an image via Message causes the "To:" field of the resulting "New Message" window to be clipped at the top. I've seen this in other apps, too (Afterlight, Lightroom, etc).

I've observed this on my iPad Air 2, running both iOS 9.2.x and 9.3.x.

Anyone else seen this, and know of a way to fix it?

-Allan

[image]